# How to validate multiple textareas with CkEditors

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-validate

In a form im using textarea with ckeditor support.

The user wil have the flexibility to add as many textareas as he wants and the ckeditors are also to load simultaneously.

now the difficulty im finding is that to validate the static textarea with ckeditor provided as well as the dynamically loaded 1s by the user.

plz suggest me the solution...

Answer (score 0):

You can enumerate all the CKEDITOR instances on your page using:

```
for(var x in CKEDITOR.instances) {
   var inst = CKEDITOR.instances[x];
   // now you can validate the value in inst
}
```

Answer (score 0):

enumerate all instences on page. Use jquery for validate all.

```
 $("#my-form-submit-button").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     CKEDITOR.instances.event-body.updateElement();
     $('#event').validate({
          // Validation code will go here
     });
})
```

It will update your ckeditor and will assign ckeditor's value to your textarea to which you integrate it.